# My mesh no longer follows my armature

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature

I'm new to blender. I'm working on a simple swimming animation for a fish model. I had everything working fine until I was getting ready to export. After applying the modifiers to my model, I later noticed that my mesh was no longer following my armature. I'm not exactly sure what it was that broke it, but I think it had something to do with applying the modifiers.

Here is the [.blend](https://ufile.io/xct90wd3).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A mesh can be modified by an armature only if it has an armature modifier pointing to the skeleton.

To bring back your animation add an armature modifier to the mesh and select your armature in its "Object" field.

[image]

As a good workflow advice, I suggest you not to animate the whole armature as object, instead you should use only bones and only in pose mode (you will have to set some bones as child of  a main bone, maybe the bigger one).